# Arabic style Page Flip/Curl in Xcode or Core Animation

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, core-animation

I want to use Page Flip/Curl transition for my Arabic ebook iPad project (left to right transition). I had research any framework or API support left to right page curl/flip, but no resource is available. Can anyone have idea how to start the things for Left to right page flip in xcode or core animation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time to wait for iOS 5.0, then you can use the new `UIPageViewController`.

If you need to do it today, then you are pretty much left on your own. The page curl filter that is used is not a public API that you can use. You would instead have to implement transformation of your own OpenGL ES mesh.